# I need to generialze a typescript method

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, refactoring

Need suggestion on generalization typescript method. Check my method below. I need to reduce number of lines of code in the method.

```
    if (authProvider === 'google') {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.setCustomParameters({
        prompt: 'select_account'
      });
      return provider;
    }
    if (authProvider === 'facebook') {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
      provider.setCustomParameters({
        prompt: 'select_account'
      });
      return provider;
    }
    if (authProvider === 'twitter') {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
      provider.setCustomParameters({
        prompt: 'select_account'
      });
      return provider;
    }
    if (authProvider === 'microsoft') {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
      provider.setCustomParameters({
        tenant: 'b7773erqqqfr5678'
      });
      return provider;
    }

I there any good way of writing method more efficiently.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace the conditions with ternary operators. Try the following

```js
someFunc() {
  const provider = authProvider === 'google' 
    ? new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    : authProvider === 'facebook'
      ? new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
      : new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
  
  provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
  return provider;
}
```

#### Update

```js
someFunc() {
  const provider = authProvider === 'google'
    ? { provider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider() }
    : authProvider === 'facebook'
      ? { provider: new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider() }
      : authProvider === 'twitter'
        ? { provider: new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider() }
        : { provider: new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com'), tenant: 'b7773erqqqfr5678' }

  (!!provider.tenant)
    ? provider.provider.setCustomParameters({ tenant: provider.tenant })
    : provider.provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' })

  return provider.provider;
}
```

Comment: In the last if condition setcustomparameters method has different value..how can I add that in your solution.

Comment: @Owais: It wasn't there in the original question. Is there any other changes you would like to make before I provide an update? Please provide the entire code in the original question. Including something after an answer and asking again is the same as posting two different questions.

Comment: Actually I missed that if condition.. sorry for that..so I have edited the question.

Comment: @Owais: I've updated the answer to include the new condition. But bear in mind the code is untested. Please check if it works as expected before using it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch case instead of nested eg

````
         const provider
         switch(authProvider) {
        
         case 'google'
           provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
         case 'facebook'
           provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
         case 'twitter'
           provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
         case 'microsoft'
           provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
        }
        
        provider.setCustomParameters({
                prompt: 'select_account'
              });
         return provider;
        ```
````

Comment: In the last if condition setCustomParameters has different value..how to use in your solution.